# Не работает этот код, делаю бота на сайте, при нажатии на кнопку просто выводит сам код

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button = types.KeyboardButton('Ввести число')
    markup.add(button)
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет! Нажми на кнопку 'Ввести число', чтобы начать.", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True and message.text == 'Ввести число')
def handle_enter_number(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Введите число, которое нужно умножить на 12.7.")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    try:
        number = float(message.text)
        result = number * 12.7
        rubles_total = result + 300 + 800 + 1000
        response = f"Итого в Юанях: {result} ¥\n\nДоставка по Китаю: 300 ₽\nДоставка Китай-Москва: 800 ₽\nКомиссия сервиса: 1000 ₽\n\nИтого в рублях: {rubles_total} ₽\n\n+ оплата доставки СДЭК из Москвы до вашей точки производится самостоятельно\n\nЕсли вы заказали более 3-х товаров за 1 раз на каждый следующий товар (4,5,6…) составляет 800р"
        bot.reply_to(message, response)
    except ValueError:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуйста, введите число.")

bot.polling()
```